# Extract multiple lines of text in XML

Tags: perl, unix

I have an XML as given below. I want to extract the text between `<com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response>` and `</com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response>`. The XML starts with `com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response` and ends with `com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!--This is a Ping Response-->
<com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response xmlns="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/ping/response" targetNamespace="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/ping/response" EchoToken="00c0d1a" TimeStamp="2016-06-21T00:01:48.191" Target="Test" Version="1.07" SequenceNmbr="1466467309030" PrimaryLangID="en" RequestorCompanyCode="1y" RequestorNetworkID="as" SetLocation="zrh">
 <Headers Trailers="n">
  <Result xmlns="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/fares/common" status="success" />
 </Headers>
 <DataArea>
  <Pong Message="pong" ServerHostName="usclsefam922.clt.travel.eds.com" ServerPortNumber="8024" ServerMessageCount="1" RegionName="preprod" SystemName="preprods3.1" SystemDate="20160621" SystemTime="148" CodeVersion="$Name: build-2016-06-17-1338 $" />
 </DataArea>
 <Trailers />
</com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response>
```

I tried with the command below but no luck:

```
    cat file.txt | egrep "<com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response>.*</com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response>"
```

Please advise.

Comment: What are you trying to extract exactly? Because this sounds like a job for a parser... and you're trying to parse XML to get some semantically identical XML. Which is a bit odd really, and sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: ([Useless use of `cat`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tried it seems egrep cannot match multiple lines, you could use pcregrep -M instead

```
pcregrep -M 'com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response((.|\n)*)com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response'
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Rule one of XML. Don't use regex. XML is a contextual language, and regular expressions cannot do that. You will have a hack, which will be brittle, and one day mysteriously break when the XML changes in a PERFECTLY VALID way.

So instead, use a parser. Perl has several options - I happen to like `XML::Twig` for being a good starting point (`XML::LibXML` is also excellent, but a steeper learning curve).

And for this, all you need is:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( comments => 'drop' )->parse ( \*DATA ); 
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$twig -> get_xpath('//com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response',0  ) -> print;


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!--This is a Ping Response-->
<com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response xmlns="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/ping/response" targetNamespace="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/ping/response" EchoToken="00c0d1a" TimeStamp="2016-06-21T00:01:48.191" Target="Test" Version="1.07" SequenceNmbr="1466467309030" PrimaryLangID="en" RequestorCompanyCode="1y" RequestorNetworkID="as" SetLocation="zrh">
 <Headers Trailers="n">
  <Result xmlns="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/fares/common" status="success" />
 </Headers>
 <DataArea>
  <Pong Message="pong" ServerHostName="usclsefam922.clt.travel.eds.com" ServerPortNumber="8024" ServerMessageCount="1" RegionName="preprod" SystemName="preprods3.1" SystemDate="20160621" SystemTime="148" CodeVersion="$Name: build-2016-06-17-1338 $" />
 </DataArea>
 <Trailers />
</com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response>
```

This outputs - as requested:

```
<com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response
    EchoToken="00c0d1a"
    PrimaryLangID="en"
    RequestorCompanyCode="1y"
    RequestorNetworkID="as"
    SequenceNmbr="1466467309030"
    SetLocation="zrh"
    Target="Test"
    TimeStamp="2016-06-21T00:01:48.191"
    Version="1.07"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/ping/response"
    xmlns="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/ping/response">
  <Headers Trailers="n">
    <Result
        status="success"
        xmlns="http://schemas.eds.com/transportation/message/fares/common"
    />
  </Headers>
  <DataArea>
    <Pong
        CodeVersion="$Name: build-2016-06-17-1338 $"
        Message="pong"
        RegionName="preprod"
        ServerHostName="usclsefam922.clt.travel.eds.com"
        ServerMessageCount="1"
        ServerPortNumber="8024"
        SystemDate="20160621"
        SystemName="preprods3.1"
        SystemTime="148"
    />
  </DataArea>
  <Trailers/>
</com.eds.travel.fares.ping.response>
```

Which is basically all of your XML, less headers and comments. Technically what you asked for, but a bit trivial. Although note the reformatting - reformatting XML is *entirely valid*. Which is why `regex` based solutions break.

So how about instead:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( 'file.txt' ); 

foreach my $pong ( $twig -> get_xpath('//Pong' ) ) { 
    foreach my $key( keys %{$pong -> atts} ) { 
        print "$key => ", $pong -> att($key),"\n";
    }
}
```

Which with your source data, prints:

```
CodeVersion => $Name: build-2016-06-17-1338 $
RegionName => preprod
SystemTime => 148
ServerHostName => usclsefam922.clt.travel.eds.com
SystemDate => 20160621
SystemName => preprods3.1
ServerMessageCount => 1
ServerPortNumber => 8024
Message => pong
```